# When is "l'un l'autre" or "les uns les autres" necessary?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-réfléchis

In this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/translation-of-help-each-other) I asked about the translation of

"The students always help each other with the homework."

and it was pointed out that in the translation, *les uns les autres* is a necessary part, otherwise the sentence would sound like a general truth.

> Les élèves s'aident toujours **les uns les autres** avec leurs devoirs.

Is "les uns les autres" (or "l'un l'autre", "l'une l'autre", "les unes les autres") always necessary in the use of reflexive verbs for two or more people? If not, when is it necessary? As examples, are the parts in parentheses in the following sentences indispensable?

> Les deux personnes se sont souvent écrit (l'une à l'autre).
>
> Ils s'envoient (l'un à l'autre) habituellement trois lettres par mois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> *Les élèves s'aident toujours les uns les autres avec leurs devoirs.*

can be simplified that way:

> *Les élèves s'**entr**aident toujours avec leurs devoirs.*

Using *s'entraident* instead of *s'aident* removes the need to specify "les uns les autres*.

I'm not sure about the meaning of *avec leurs devoirs*. It can be understood to mean "they help each other using(?) their homework". Perhaps you want *pour (faire) leurs devoirs* meaning "they help each other to do their homework":

> *Les élèves s'**entr**aident toujours pour leurs devoirs.*

*L'une à l'autre* is not necessary in the next sentence, there is no doubt that when one of the persons writes, the letter for the other one:

> *Les deux personnes se sont souvent écrit.*

No need to use *l'un à l'autre* either in the last one although the sentence is ambiguous; it can be a three letters altogether or three letters each:

> Ils s'envoient habituellement trois lettres par mois.

This sentence would make clear it is the three letters each case:

> Chacun envoie trois lettres par mois à l'autre.

Comment: "Les élèves s'entraident toujours avec leurs devoirs" also could be translated as "The students help each other doing their homework". It doesn't have to be literal to mean the same thing. It's kind of implicite. Figurative.

Comment: @Shozs Yes, it might also be understood as intended but it is much less idiomatic. [Google Ngram find no occurrence of "s'entraident avec":](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27entraident+avec%2Cs%27entraident+pour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%27entraident%20pour%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Still, I don't understand why "les uns les autres" is needed in "Les élèves s'aident toujours les uns les autres pour leurs devoirs." but not the other sentences? Doesn't using "s'aident" already specify that the action is reciprocal?

Comment: The issue is the pronominal *s'aider* has a wider meaning. *Les élèves s'aident pour faire leur devoir.* might be understood as an unfinished statement leading to the question: *Ils s'aident de quoi ?* There is no such ambiguity with *s'écrire / s'envoyer des lettres*

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "Ils s'aident de quoi ?", but wouldn't the answer be "Ils s'aident de faire leur devoir"?

Comment: The answer might be *ils s'aident de leur notes*, *ils s'aident de Google* or in our case, *il ne s'aident de rien, ils s'aident entre eux*. *S'aider* doesn't imply reciprocity (think "help yourself"), the reason why "help each other" is better translated by *s'aider les uns les autres* or *s'entraider*.